# casper.open(...) issue when the url doesn't exit

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I would like make a sample script allows to check a list of url (pass from a csv file). Foreach urls, the script return if the url return an error (404, 500..) or not.

So, after several tries, I almost do that but...I noticed when the URL doesn't exit (example; http://akljdlkzjlkadz.jhjkhkajzhd), my casper.open has no time for get the error (500) before the next casperjs step '.then' begin. I mean :

this is my function who contains the two casperjs steps ;

```
function check(line){
  this.then(function(){ //step one
    url = line.split("|");
    this.echo("TEST0 : "+url[0]);
    this.open(url[0]);
  });

  this.then( function (){ //step two
    if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404){
      this.warn("Error 404");
    }else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500){
      this.warn("Error 500");
    }else{
      this.echo("TEST1 : "+url[0]);
      this.echo("TEST2 : "+this.getCurrentUrl());
      this.echo("Link OK !");
    }
  });

}
```

And With the several this.echo(..), my terminal shows that :

```
TEST0 : http://www.google.com 
TEST1 : http://www.google.com
TEST2 : http://www.google.com
LINK OK!
TEST0 : http://www.google.es
TEST1 : http://www.google.es
TEST2 : http://www.google.es
LINK OK!
TEST0 : http://www.google.azerty
TEST1 : http://www.google.azerty
TEST2 : http://www.google.es <----- getCurrentUrl() doesn't return http://www.google.azerty, has no time because this url doesn't exist?
LINK OK!
```

I tried several way for fix that..but I don't find and understand why the second .then begin whereas the first .then wasn't finish.

```
casperjs version : 1.1.0-beta3
phantomjs version : 1.9.7
nodejs version : v0.10.25
```

And the fully code of my script ;

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false
  }
});
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = casper.cli.get(0);
var url;

function check(line){
  this.then(function(){
    url = line.split("|");
    this.echo("TEST0 : "+url[0]);
    this.open(url[0]);
  });

  this.then( function (){
    if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 404){
      this.warn("Error 404");
    }else if (this.currentHTTPStatus === 500){
      this.warn("Error 500");
    }else{
      this.echo("TEST1 : "+url[0]);
      this.echo("TEST2 : "+this.getCurrentUrl());
      this.echo("Link OK !");
    }
  });

}

function main(){
  this.then(function(){
    var stream = fs.open(csv, 'r');
    var line = stream.readLine();
    line = stream.readLine();
    while(line){
      check.call(this, line);
      line = stream.readLine();
    }
  });
}

casper.start().then(main).run();
```

Comment: Does it behave the same if you exchange `open` for `thenOpen`? Note: CasperJS runs on top of PhantomJS which doesn't use node at all.

Comment: I tried with thenOpen, but I didn't find how I can pass the url argument genered from the previous .then (scope variable problem). And yet, I declare the url variable at the begin of my code (so, this variable is global ?). So, when I use ".thenOpen(url, function..." for the step two, the program return an error (variable not found)

Comment: I meant a replace without changing anything else. That should lead to the error you describe.

Comment: If I replace the open by thenOpen, the problem keeps the same (I hope I understood what you meant x) )